# Validating autopopulated textbox using selenium web driver, java

Tags: selenium, web, driver

I have a scenario in which there is a text box and when i type something in that text box it auto-populates.
I need to trace that auto populated values and verify that it contains the string that i have entered in the text field.
Can someone please help me out with this.?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

Below code is for getting auto populated result for google site.

```
driver.get("http://www.google.co.in");
driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("Test");
List<WebElement> autoPopulatedList=driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("tr>td>span"));
for(WebElement ele:autoPopulatedList)
{
      System.out.println(ele.getText());
      if(ele.getText().contains("Test"))
      {
             System.out.println("Your case passed..!!");
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.get(URL); // URL = http://www.google.co.in;

driver.findElement(By.id(id_of_the_element)).sendKeys(value); //Value for the field

List autoPopulatedList=driver.findElements(auto_populate_element_path);

int autoPopulateSize = autoPopulatedList.length(); // Take the auto populate size to compare

int testedSize = 0; //initialize a variable for testing

for(WebElement element : autoPopulatedList){

     if(element.getText().contains(value)) //Checking the autopopulated list with the value

     {

           testedSize++;  // this will add 1 if the autopopulate contains the value

     }

}

if(autoPopulateSize == testedSize){

     System.out.println("Autopopulate contains the values");
}else{

 System.out.println("Fail");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Send text threw Sendkey And then get field value like this :

```
    driver.findElement(By.id("field ID here")).sendkeys("ABC");
    String strActualValue = driver.findElement(By.id("field ID here")).getAttribute("value");
    System.out.println("Field value is = "+strActualValue +"");
```

it will print the value which you have sent by send key and the value which was auto-populated in the field.

```
    Result : ABC1234
    ABC is your value 1234 is auto-populated value.
```

ENJOY!